# Por que cuando pruebo mi juego en android no me manda a las scena que quiero?

Tags: c#, unity, 3d

Tengo este codigo:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
```

public class intro : MonoBehaviour {

```
// Use this for initialization
void Update () {
    StartCoroutine ("returne");
}
public IEnumerator returne(){
    yield return new WaitForSeconds (3.06f);
    SceneManager.LoadScene ("main");
}
```

}

 practicamente hago que al pasar 3.06f pase a la otra escena, en unity todo bien y cuando lo compilo a pc tambien, pero a la hora de compilar y probar en android no me carga, se me queda tildado, lo mismo pasa cuando quiero presionar un boton para entrar a otra escena, ayuda porfavor

Comment: Te sugiero revises [ask] para realizar una pregunta, añadiendo información que ayude a solucionar el problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya encontre el error, en player settings estaba tildado split application binary y ese era el problema, ya funciona perfectamente

Comment: Lo que comentas no existe en tu pregunta original, de hecho **¿te refieres a que el problema es solo un error tipográfico?**